# Windows Phone IsolatedStorageSettings Save issue

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

So basically I have 2 projects, 1 my project and the 2nd a scheduledagent.

In the scheduledAgent I make a server call (my app gets deactivated) and I want to save the reply into isolatedstorage, after which my app gets reactived.

So after my app gets reactivated I want to load the value that I saved in the scheduledAgent, but the problem is it is null everytime. (I am calling the save method)

code for scheduledagent:

so inside the OnInvoke method:

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("token");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("token", grant_token);
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

(App gets reactivated)

code which continues to read the saved info:

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue("token", out reply);
```

The problem is that "reply" is always empty, and grant_token does contain a value when saving

any feedback will help

thanx!
B

Comment: http://www.david-amador.com/2010/10/using-isolatedstorage-to-saveload-files-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: I think the values are loaded the first time you call `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`, and kept in memory. So even if you call `Save` you won't have the new values, as they won't be read again. As a workaround, I suggest you manually save/read the values from the isolated storage, rather than using `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your scheduled agent exiting correctly? IsolatedStorageSettings won't save if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I have managed to fixed this by saving my data to a txtfile, and just reading it from the txtfile again. But just for interest sake is there a specific way to check if the agent exits correctly? I just followed the example on Microsoft's site, and added the saving of value to that code.

Comment: Yes - from within your app itself, you can retrieve the PeriodicTask, and check its LastExitReason - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledtask.lastexitreason(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I developed a quick and easy Isolated Storage DLL that is free to use and allows you to save anything that inherits from Object (so basically everything). If you have anymore issues I would give it a try it's pretty simple.

```
Object whatEverYouWantToSave = new Object();

EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("MyFileName",whatEverYouWantToSave ):
```

That's it! It serializes it to the isolated storage for you. No mess.

You can download it at http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47